# vb.net objects property value changed event

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, events, inotifypropertychanged

I'm looking for a way to implement a property change event for a object class. Whenever a certain value changes it needs to recalculate the items mass.

I have searched some topic's and may have found a solution, only problem for me is that `c#` is unreadable for me ( for now ).

[Link to topic c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246777/raise-an-event-whenever-a-propertys-value-changed)

After doing some more digging, if also found a vb.net solution, in the answer they refer to MSDN page. But the sample there is removed.

[Link to topic vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996051/variable-property-changed-event-in-vb-net)

I also found this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms743695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> How to: Implement Property Change Notification

But if I check the current framework it read: "This topic is no longer available"

So my guess something has changed for this event during changing of framework? Or is this still the active method to do this as described in the vb.net solution?

Add code of class

```
Public Class BodyComponent

' Basic properties that are required for all of the bodycompenents
' regardless of the type.

<Browsable(True)> Public Property Type()
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Height() As Double
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Thickness() As Double
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Elevation() As Double
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Auto_Diameter() As Boolean
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Diameter() As Double
<Browsable(True)> Public Property Mass() As Double


' Type Enum that defines what kind of body component is created.
Public Enum BodyComponentType
    Cylinder = 0001
    Cone_reduction = 0002
End Enum
```

and the derived class

```
Public Class Body_Cylinder

' Get the base properties
Inherits BodyComponent

' Set new properties that are only required for cylinders
Public Property Segments() As Integer
Public Property LW_Orientation() As Double

Public Shared Count As Integer = 0

Public Sub New()
    count = count + 1
End Sub

' Remove Cylinder from collection and change the count
Public Shared Sub delete_cylinder(ByVal oItem As Integer, ByRef oBinding As BindingSource)

    oBinding.RemoveAt(oItem)
    Count = Count - 1

End Sub

' Calculate mass
Private Sub Calc_mass()

    ' HACK: create material list where rho is defined for other
    ' material types
    Dim rho As Double
    rho = 8

    Dim oVolume As Double
    oVolume = Math.PI / 4 * ((Diameter + 2 * Thickness) ^ 2 - Diameter ^ 2) * Height

    Mass = oVolume * rho
End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc31b696.aspx

Comment: I think the OP means how to implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You might refine what you want because it may be as simple as not using an auto implemented property.

Comment: @Plutonix could you please clarify?

Comment: That is what I was asking you to do.  Provide a portion of the class related to this.

Comment: @Plutonix i added the class to clarify

Comment: Better...presumably you want to `Calc_mass` whenever D, T, or H changes?

Comment: Yes, or the material but I didnt include that property, but that will be the same operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example written in **VisualBasic.Net** taken from **[this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**.

```
' This class implements a simple customer type 
' that implements the IPropertyChange interface.

Public Class DemoCustomer
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    ' These fields hold the values for the public properties.
    Private idValue As Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
    Private customerName As String = String.Empty
    Private companyNameValue As String = String.Empty
    Private phoneNumberValue As String = String.Empty

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
      Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub


    ' The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern.
    Private Sub New() 
        customerName = "no data"
        companyNameValue = "no data"
        phoneNumberValue = "no data"

    End Sub 'New


    ' This is the public factory method.
    Public Shared Function CreateNewCustomer() As DemoCustomer 
        Return New DemoCustomer()

    End Function

    ' This property represents an ID, suitable
    ' for use as a primary key in a database.
    Public ReadOnly Property ID() As Guid
        Get
            Return Me.idValue
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Property CompanyName() As String 
        Get
            Return Me.companyNameValue
        End Get 
        Set
            If value <> Me.companyNameValue Then
                Me.companyNameValue = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CompanyName")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property PhoneNumber() As String 
        Get
            Return Me.phoneNumberValue
        End Get 
        Set
            If value <> Me.phoneNumberValue Then
                Me.phoneNumberValue = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Sources for your study:

- **[INotifyPropertyChanged Interface - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**
- **[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**
- **[How to: Implement Property Change Notification - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**