# Apply Property Changed Event

Tags: vb.net

I realize this might be spoon feeding but I've already tried many other ways to do this but to no avail. I've already researched a lot including this one which I think might be the right way "[variable/property changed event in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996051/variable-property-changed-event-in-vb-net)" but I cant get it to work the way I want it . Im new to coding and I'm trying to add an on change event on my variable so here's my sample.

```
Public Class FormMode
    Public Property ViewMode As Boolean
    Public Property EditMode As Boolean
    Public Property NewMode As Boolean
End Class
```

So basically I have forms and each of them has their own FormMode. The form modes can only be true 1 at a time i. e.

```
ViewMode = True
EditMode = False
NewMode = False
```

Or

```
ViewMode = False
EditMode = True
NewMode = False
```

Or

```
ViewMode = False
EditMode = False
NewMode = True
```

The User can and will change the mode of the form. What I want is if they change ViewMode = True the EditMode and NewMode must be automatically be set to false. Same case to the other two. Please note that they will change to value from another form. Also I want to be able to look at if the form is in what form (ViewMode/EditMode/NewMode). Am I doing this the right way or should I try a different approach? Please bear with my noobish and redundant question as I already tried my best to dothis but unfortunately failed. Thank a lot!

Comment: A) Rather than 3 booleans to indicate *one* state, consider an `Enum` (examine the ListView's View property) B) `INotifyPropertyChanged` is overkill.  It is meant for a class to notify other things of a change.  You dont need to notify yourself.  If you still think 3 properties for one state is a good idea, dont use Auto properties and reset the others in the setters. C) Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Thank you. I used the enum as you suggested and I managed to get it done. I wasnt aware of that before now I know better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted as an answer won't work as you expect. Each time that you check to see if `IsView` is true, your code will actually set `TFormMode` to `FormMode.ViewMode` and wont actually return a true or false boolean - the same is the case for `IsNew` and `IsEdit`

What you should do is use the code below. I'll explain with a walkthrough.

Declaring `_TFormMode` as a private variable gives your class a variable to work with internally and it isn't directly visible to the outside world

Your Enum is fine as it is.

Declaring `TFormMode` as the public property gives the code outside your class a safe way of interacting with the private field `_TFormMode`. This way, using the `Set` and `Get` code blocks, you can add any validation code or return whatever information you like. This makes you `UpdateTFormMode` sub redunant.

The function `IsView` will now return the result of the expression `_TFormMode = FormMode.ViewMode`.

A longer version of

```
Return _TFormMode = FormMode.ViewMode
```

would be

```
If _TFormMode = FormMode.ViewMode Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

The remaining functions do the same thing, but test against the other Enum values

```
Public Class Form1
        Private _TFormMode As FormMode

        Public Enum FormMode
            ViewMode
            EditMode
            NewMode
        End Enum

        Public Property TFormMode As FormMode
            Set(value As FormMode)
                _TFormMode = value
            End Set
            Get
                Return _TFormMode
            End Get
        End Property


        Public Function IsView() As Boolean
            Return _TFormMode = FormMode.ViewMode
        End Function

        Public Function IsNew() As Boolean
            Return _TFormMode = FormMode.NewMode
        End Function

        Public Function IsEdit() As Boolean
            Return _TFormMode = FormMode.EditMode
        End Function

    End Class
```

Comment: You're correct. I only tested my code before once so i didn't managed to get around it. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I used `enum` as suggested and managed to fit it in my needs .Thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Property TFormMode As FormMode
    Public Enum FormMode
       ViewMode
       EditMode
       NewMode
    End Enum

    Public Function IsView() As Boolean
        TFormMode = FormMode.ViewMode
    End Function

    Public Function IsNew() As Boolean
        TFormMode = FormMode.NewMode
    End Function

    Public Function IsEdit() As Boolean
        TFormMode = FormMode.EditMode
    End Function

    Public Sub UpdateFormMode(Mode As FormMode)
        TFormMode = Mode
    End Sub
End Class
```

I still made the 3 boolean just so its easier to check if its in a certain mode or not.