# How do I hookup for each setter

Tags: vb.net, properties

I am programming vb.net. I would like to register everytime a property has been "set". But rather than create a Sub and call it from every property setter, I'd like it to be triggered automatically any time the setter is called. Is there any kind of "hookup" system I can use to achieve this?

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to do this in a completely automated fashion for a property whose type is a primitive e.g. `Integer` or `Boolean`.  If you have some sort of a wrapper object type, then you could overload assignment to also do whatever kind of a hook or event it is that you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing thread that explains how you can achieve this using the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface:
[Implementing INotifyPropertyChangedEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996051/variable-property-changed-event-in-vb-net)

Comment: But in that thread they actually make a call to a function inside the setter, which is what I want to avoid, the need to modify each and every setter to make the notification.

Comment: It's not necessarily a function. It's an event. It notifies the calling object that a property from the current object is changed. To achieve what you want you will need to either create your own event or implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.

Comment: @rwynnchristian But the reply is correct: even with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it's still necessary to add a function call in the setter to raise the event.